# Show custom error page for PUT requests sent to JSP with Jetty 9.4

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty

**Background**

When upgrading from Spring 4 to 5.3 the error page specified in `web.xml` no longer worked for certain HTTP verbs, one of these was `PUT`. For example, when a `PUT` request to a Spring controller resulted in an unexpected error, the error page defined in `web.xml` was not shown. Instead, we got an error along the lines of `405 Method Not Allowed`. The error page was shown correctly for `GET` requests. The error page was (and is still) defined like this in `web.xml`:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>
```

"uncaughtException" is a tiles view defined like this:

```xml
<definition extends="siteDefault" name="uncaughtException">
     <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/uncaughtException.jspx"/>
</definition>
```

To get this working for all HTTP verbs we added this Spring Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping("/uncaughtException")
@Controller
public class UncaughtExceptionViewController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String uncaughtException() {
        return "uncaughtException";
    }

}
```

Now the error page was shown correctly even for `PUT` requests.

Previously we used Jetty 9.2 but when upgrading to Java 14 we were also forced to upgrade to Jetty 9.4. When doing this we noticed that the error page was no longer shown for `PUT` requests (it works for `GET`) even though we still have the `UncaughtExceptionViewController` controller. Instead, the `405 Method Not Allowed` error is back. During debugging we noticed that the `uncaughtException` in `UncaughtExceptionViewController` is not called when using Jetty 9.4.

**Question**

How can we configure Jetty or Spring MVC to show the error page even for `PUT` requests and not only for `GET` and not show us `405 Method Not Allowed`?

### Update

After setting a break-point in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.setStatus` I see that the problem seems to be that "JSPs only permit GET, POST or HEAD. Jasper also permits OPTIONS". The full stack-trace is:

```
sendError:454, Response (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
sendError:158, HttpServletResponseWrapper (javax.servlet.http)
sendError:119, OnCommittedResponseWrapper (org.springframework.session.web.http)
sendError:158, HttpServletResponseWrapper (javax.servlet.http)
sendError:158, HttpServletResponseWrapper (javax.servlet.http)
sendError:119, OnCommittedResponseWrapper (org.springframework.security.web.util)
sendError:158, HttpServletResponseWrapper (javax.servlet.http)
sendError:119, OnCommittedResponseWrapper (org.springframework.security.web.util)
_jspService:1, site_005fdefault_jspx (org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts)
service:71, HttpJspBase (org.apache.jasper.runtime)
service:790, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
service:476, JspServletWrapper (org.apache.jasper.servlet)
serviceJspFile:386, JspServlet (org.apache.jasper.servlet)
service:330, JspServlet (org.apache.jasper.servlet)
service:106, JettyJspServlet (org.eclipse.jetty.jsp)
service:790, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
service:1402, ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
handle:763, ServletHolder (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doHandle:569, ServletHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
handle:143, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:620, SecurityHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.security)
handle:127, HandlerWrapper (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
nextHandle:235, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doHandle:1610, SessionHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
nextHandle:233, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doHandle:1377, ContextHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
nextScope:188, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doScope:507, ServletHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doScope:1580, SessionHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
nextScope:186, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doScope:1292, ContextHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:141, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
forward:219, Dispatcher (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
forward:78, Dispatcher (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
forward:407, SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$SessionCommittingRequestDispatcher (org.springframework.session.web.http)
forward:265, ServletRequest (org.apache.tiles.request.servlet)
doForward:228, ServletRequest (org.apache.tiles.request.servlet)
dispatch:57, AbstractClientRequest (org.apache.tiles.request)
render:47, DispatchRenderer (org.apache.tiles.request.render)
render:259, BasicTilesContainer (org.apache.tiles.impl)
render:397, BasicTilesContainer (org.apache.tiles.impl)
render:238, BasicTilesContainer (org.apache.tiles.impl)
render:221, BasicTilesContainer (org.apache.tiles.impl)
render:59, DefinitionRenderer (org.apache.tiles.renderer)
renderMergedOutputModel:147, TilesView (org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3)
render:316, AbstractView (org.springframework.web.servlet.view)
render:1373, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processDispatchResult:1118, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doDispatch:1057, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doService:943, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processRequest:1006, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doPut:920, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:710, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
service:883, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:790, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
handle:763, ServletHolder (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilter:1651, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilter:226, WebSocketUpgradeFilter (org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server)
doFilter:1638, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilterInternal:186, OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter (org.springframework.orm.jpa.support)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:1638, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilter:317, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
invoke:127, FilterSecurityInterceptor (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept)
doFilter:91, FilterSecurityInterceptor (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:114, ExceptionTranslationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.access)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:137, SessionManagementFilter (org.springframework.security.web.session)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:111, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:158, RememberMeAuthenticationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:170, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (org.springframework.security.web.servletapi)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:63, RequestCacheAwareFilter (org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:158, BasicAuthenticationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:200, AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:116, LogoutFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:66, HeaderWriterFilter (org.springframework.security.web.header)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:56, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:105, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context)
doFilter:331, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:214, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:177, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
invokeDelegate:358, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:271, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:1638, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilterInternal:94, HiddenHttpMethodFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:1638, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilterInternal:201, CharacterEncodingFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:1638, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilterInternal:40, CorsFilter (com.mycompany.spring)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:1638, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doFilterInternal:141, SessionRepositoryFilter (org.springframework.session.web.http)
doFilter:82, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.session.web.http)
invokeDelegate:358, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:271, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:1638, ServletHandler$CachedChain (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doHandle:567, ServletHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
handle:143, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:578, SecurityHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.security)
handle:127, HandlerWrapper (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
nextHandle:235, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doHandle:1610, SessionHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
nextHandle:233, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doHandle:1377, ContextHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
nextScope:188, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doScope:507, ServletHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
doScope:1580, SessionHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
nextScope:186, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
doScope:1292, ContextHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:141, ScopedHandler (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:191, ContextHandlerCollection (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:146, HandlerCollection (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:127, HandlerWrapper (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler)
handle:501, Server (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
lambda$handle$1:383, HttpChannel (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
dispatch:-1, 435181768 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$$Lambda$1064)
dispatch:556, HttpChannel (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
handle:375, HttpChannel (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
onFillable:273, HttpConnection (org.eclipse.jetty.server)
succeeded:311, AbstractConnection$ReadCallback (org.eclipse.jetty.io)
fillable:105, FillInterest (org.eclipse.jetty.io)
run:104, ChannelEndPoint$1 (org.eclipse.jetty.io)
runTask:336, EatWhatYouKill (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy)
doProduce:313, EatWhatYouKill (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy)
tryProduce:171, EatWhatYouKill (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy)
produce:135, EatWhatYouKill (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy)
run:-1, 976266910 (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$1056)
runJob:806, QueuedThreadPool (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread)
run:938, QueuedThreadPool$Runner (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread)
run:832, Thread (java.lang)
```

Comment: It depends on where the 405 is being generated from. (the context-less jetty layer? the WebApp layer? the servlet-api itself? the Spring layer? the Spring MVC layer? etc.)  each layer has it's own handling of errors that originate on that layer.

Comment: Put break points on the two `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.setStatus` methods (and `.sendError` method) to trigger when 405 is set.  See what the stacktrace is at that point in time.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I've updated the question to include the stracktrace now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is produced by JSP.

The standard Servlet Error-Page handling can be used.

The `WEB-INF/web.xml` can be defined to respond to status code 405.

```xml
  <error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/myMethodNotAllowedPath</location>
  </error-page>
```

You can also, optionally, define a global error page error handler like this ..

```xml
  <error-page>
    <location>/myGlobalErrorHandler</location>
  </error-page>
```

Since Servlet 3.0, the `<error-page>` can define a reaction based on a status code `<error-code>`, an exception `<exception-type>`, or nothing (which means all errors not caught by more specific definitions)

The Servlet implementation will redispatch the request to the defined `<location>` with `DispatcherType.ERROR`, and the details of the original request can be found in the [`HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) values under the various keys/names defined in the [`RequestDispatcher.ERROR_*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) constants.

Comment: Amazing! Just removing "<exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>" from error-page seems to have fixed it! I know you're not supposed to say thanks on SO, but this time I can't resist, THANK YOU!